# How to add Subtitles to already created video file for .avi format on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, video-recording, subtitles

Can I create subtitle (.srt) file manually (to add subtitle) for .avi file?

I have created .avi file using Snagit but there is no option to add subtitle as well. So can I create subtitle file manually by myself? Or Do I have to download a specific Software for it?

Does it follows any structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched on net and found that it's very to add subtitle to any `.avi` file format. Here is a link for a site called [Any Video Converter](http://www.any-video-converter.com/add-srt-subtitle-to-output-video.php) where an example has been given that How to create `.srt` file for Subtitles?

For quick view, below I am specifying format for Subtitle file (.srt)

```
1
00:00:03,000 --> 00:00:07,000
Hi Friends, This is First Track

2
00:00:14,000 --> 00:00:17,000
Second Track goes here

3
00:00:18,000 --> 00:00:22,000
Third Track goes here
```

So, we have to just follow this format. There should be a new line between each track. That's it.

`00:00:18,000` is format of `hh:mm:ss:ms`. So it's pretty simple.

Comment: [Any Video Converter violates the FFmpeg license.](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4975)

Answer (score 2):

This can also be accomplished if you have [VirtualDubMod](http://virtualdubmod.sourceforge.net/) and a TextSub provider installed such as [VobSub](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/VobSub) or [VSFilter](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/VSFilter-DirectVobSub).

To use VobSub, during installation you **must** select the **Plugins -> TextSub for VirtualDub and Avisynth** option.

To use VSFilter, you must locate the `VSFilter.dll` file in the installation directory and copy it to the `plugins` folder with the extension changed to `.vdf` (e.g. `VirtualDubMod\plugins\VSFilter.vdf`).

Once you've installed one of them:

1. Open the .avi file in VirtualDubMod
2. Select **Video -> Filters** from the menu or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
3. Click **Add** and select **TextSub** from the filters list and press **OK**
4. A file navigator should have appeared, select the `.srt` file.
5. Optionally, at this point set up the compression under **Video -> Compression**. Save the merged file with **File -> Save as AVI**